# -HD image file not found?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Why am I getting

> cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning HD file not found: META-hd.png

If I definitely have META-hd.png file in my project?

What I am doing is running my .tmx tilemap. The map uses a tileset that searches for "META.png" (without -hd suffix since I am expecting cocos2d to automatically put it on).

Comment: Is the file added to your target?

Comment: Hm, sorry, I am new to this - how can I check such thing? I never had this problem before :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the problem. I only do have -hd versions of my files. But I don't have "non-hd" versions. And for some reason, CCFileUtils will throw me errors when I don't have *both* types in my project.

Comment: to test it, very important: clean the project but also UNINSTALL it from the device / emulator

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the image is part of the app's target. If it was included as part of a group, and say there was a duplicate on file 10 of 25, the copy stops and files 1-9 are NOT tagged as part of the target. You have to go back and sweep the floor by hand.

In Xcode 4 show the assistant editor, and click the resource in the navigator. The target membership will be shown. If your app is not checked, click on that and voilà, the file will now be found.

In rare cases, i have had to clean the target and recompile to make this effective.

Comment: I have seen the file and the target membership is already checked.

Comment: well then "in rare cases .... " , clean your target and rebuild. Also verify the case on HD/hd.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will have to have a -hd version of the tilemap as well: meta.tmx and meta-hd.tmx.

Also be sure that your image file is named META-hd.png and not META-HD.png and both images use the same case: META.png and META-hd.png. The iPhone file system is case sensitive (not the iOS Simulator though).